# Selecting dropdown in selenium webdriver, dropdown list of elements in ul of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

I am new to the Selenium Web Driver technology, below is my question and unable to find out the solution please any one help me to find out the by x path or by cs Selector or by name.

below is code is the drop down Element in the page,

```
            <div id="reportsManager_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-active" style="width: 220px;">
             <a class="chzn-single" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
              <span>Ajay Paul Chowdhury</span>
               <div>
                <b></b>
               </div>
             </a>
            <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 218px; top: 24px;">
             <div class="chzn-search">
              <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 183px;">
            </div>
            <ul class="chzn-results">
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">All</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">wer</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">sss</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_4" class="active-result result-selected" style="">www</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">rrr</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">yyy</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_7" class="active-result" style="">iii</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_8" class="active-result" style="">ooo</li>
                <li id="reportsManager_chzn_o_9" class="active-result" style="">ppp</li>
```

for the above code unable to find out the xpath/cssselector/name for the  so that i can Dynamically Select the any dropdown value from the List

Please any one help me to find out the result.

for above code i tried

**1) try 1**

```
    // by Xpath and it selects the list by list ID 
    
       Actions manager = new Actions(driver);
       WebElement we1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='reportsManager_chzn_o_23']"));
      manager.moveToElement(we1).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='reportsManager_chzn_o_3']"))).click().build().perform();
       Thread.sleep(3000);
```

*above Selenium code will Select the dropdown element '**sss**' i need code which select
by name so that i can paramaterize the Dropdown List*

**2) try 2**

```
      driver.findElement(By.id("reportsManager_chzn")).findElement(By.cssSelector("chzn-single")).findElement(By.name("sss")).click();
```

showing the error message

***org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"chzn-single"}***

and the Selenium testcase is failed

**3) try 3**

tried by *Select*

```
   Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("reportsManager_chzn")));
```

selectBox.selectByVisibleText("sss");

for the above shows the Error message found div instead of select

also i tried in all the way, finally i'm here

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've already answered on this question in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499108/how-to-select-an-element-from-drop-down-list-from-the-following-html-code-using/25499309#25499309)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method with parameterized xPath:

```
public void selector(String whichItem)
{
 String xPath_partial_1 ="//ul[@class='chzn-results']/li[reportsManager_chzn_o_"
 String xPath_parameterized = whichItem;    //This can be 1/2/3/4
 String xPath_partial_2 = "]";
 String final_xPath = xPath_partial_1 + xPath_parameterized + xPath_partial_2 ; //You can use this xPath to locate your element. Note that this xpath depends upon the number. Pass the correct number(i.e. 1 for selecting All, 2 for selecting wer and so on) to select the necessary item from the DD list
 WebElement we1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='reportsManager_chzn_o_23']"));  //Could not locate this element in your codesnippet but assuming this is somewhere within the hierrarchy
 Actions manager = new Actions(driver);manager.moveToElement(we1).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xPath))).click().build().perform(); //Just replaced the xPath with the String. 

}
```

Note that since Select tag was not used in the DOM, Select Class cannot be used here. Lemme know if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the your valuable response  I tried this way , i need to select by the name of the Element/manager so that i can parameterize the Dropdown in the test method. i heard that i need to set the id for Dropdown main list , then only i can select by name of the Element/Manager. ....... Sorry for the delay in reply

Answer (score 0):

I've already posted answer on same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499108/how-to-select-an-element-from-drop-down-list-from-the-following-html-code-using/25499309#25499309). 
For java solution will be next (not sure about java syntax):

```
var dropDown = driver.findElement(By.Css(".chzn-results"));
//expand main dropDown menu before accessing to child elements    
dropDown.Click()
var dropDownElements = dropDown.findElements(By.Css(".active-result"));
foreach(var dropDownElement in dropDownElements)
{
    dropDownElement.Click();
}
//or your can access to element using index
dropDownElements[0].Click();
```

If you want access to dropDown element using it text, better solution add attribute to your li element (e.g. li name="valueFromDropDown")

Comment: Eglov Thanks for your response I tried this way, I have to select the dropdown by name/manager so that i can parametarize the Elements in Dropdown from Excel Sheet, From this above way i can't parameterize the Dropdown by the integers {dropDownElements[0]}, Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you...

```
List <WebElement> allelements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-select-choices-row-5-39']/a/span"));

  for(int i=0;i<allelements.size();i++){
  String text=allelements.get(i).getText();
    if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Test_Region1"))
    {
    allelements.get(i).click();
    break;
    } 
    }
```